# Find and replace text in a PDF

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a file that I want to remove all dollar signs ($) from a PDF (ex: find `$` and replace with );How do I do this?

I can't seem to find/don't think there is a *Find & Replace* dialog box (anywhere).

Is there another way I can do this?

The document has been OCRed and I need to remove the dollar sign before moving to word/excel...

Comment: move to word/excel and then replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infix PDF editor from [Iceni](http://bit.ly/HcoUzq). It's like a word processor for PDF documents, supporting search and replace.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to "infix PDF editor"

Comment: Requests like that will put Google out of business! Here, try [Iceni's website...](http://bit.ly/HcoUzq)

Comment: As a Google lover, I must upvote and accept your answer. (Please just add the link to your answer, to make the answer mrore complete.)Thank you very much, its exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The Adobe Acrobat **Viewer** cannot edit PDf files. Adobe and other companies sell products that can. There are also Free PDF editors available.

See Wikipedia's [List of PDF software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software)

Answer (score 0):

There is some softwares that they edit pdf files direcly like [Simple PDF Text Replacer](http://pdfmagus.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=56&Itemid=68)

Comment: For this to be considered an answer, you'll need to expand and explain.